# AsyncStorage Done() Call

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I wonder what is done() after AsyncStorage call and can I call it after catch() too?
What will happen if I don't call done()?

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('vehicle')
             .then(json => {})
             .done();
```

Comment: BTW, this question is related to promises. Search for **done** in http://www.terrencewatson.com/2015/03/10/promises/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the comments and blogs I got it.

If you will use AsyncStorage inside AsyncStorage you should call done() on the outer Promise so you can catch the **nested** AsyncStorage errors.