# this._loadInitialState(...).done is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am just beginning a week on react native, and i am following a youtube tutorial. But i am getting an error on `this._loadInitialState(...).done is not a function`. Why is that? In the code of the tutorial it works for him? I put some arrows inside  the code which line it is where i am getting the error.

I tried to google but there is not much information about it.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
this line error --->>>>>>    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }

  _loadInitialState = async () => {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    if (value !== null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
    }
  };
}
```

Thank you for your help guy's, i appreciate it.

***EDIT (another .done() function that causes error)**

```
login = () => {
    fetch("http://192.168.1.16:19006/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        alert(res.message);

        if (res.success === true) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("user", res.user);
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
        } else {
          alert(res.message);
        }
this line ->>>> }).done();
  };
}
```

It's on this line: >> }).done();

The error is : TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).done is not a function

Comment: Doesn't look like you return anything from `_loadInitialState`, specifically, an object that has a `done` property on it that is callable as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, `done` seems to be related to the [q promise module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46709924/asyncstorage-done-call) used in Angular, but this is react, just return the resolved promise, I don't think you need the call to `done`, as it won't work.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._loadInitialState() // returns promise, so process in chain
    .then(value => {
      if (value !== null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
      }
    });

}

_loadInitialState = async () => {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");

  return value;
};
```

or

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const value = await this._loadInitialState() // returns promise, await resolve

  if (value !== null) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile");
  }
}

_loadInitialState = async () => {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");

  return value;
};
```

Comment: I am not getting an error so it works! I am still figuring out what this code does haha. I am just learning this for a couple of days and i love it. I thank you for your answer you really explained it good. My question is why does the done function work with the youtube teacher but not with me? And my second question (if you have time) to explain the code to me. My languages are php,html,css,sql now

Comment: I would have to see that video to see how the code is setup to help there. What more would you like an explanation on?

Comment: I have another problem where .done()  is also used but i don't know how to change that in something else. Can you PLEASE see my edit, i want it to work so bad

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should have explained a bit more the difference between now built-in javascript promises and older Angular's earlier promise implementation, but basically the gist now is Promises are supported in standard javascript so third party modules are not needed. This particular promise module seems to have used a function named `done` to indicate a promise had resolved, or completed in some way. In ES6 JS Promises return another Promise, or "Thenable". Here is the current [Promise documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Long story short, you don't need the `done` from whatever Promise module that tutorial is using, but handle whatever the "done" function was doing in the newer Promise or async/await pattern.